# Deserializar Json en C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hola tengo un problema para deserializar un Json en C# Xamarin, quisiera sacar un JWT que me retorna un web service pero en el momento de poder sacarlo para anexarlo al modelo siempre me aparece como NULL quisiera saber que podría estar mal:

Tengo el siguiente modelo:

```
namespace Training_In_Media.Models
{
    public class Content
    {
        //Web Service Result
        [JsonProperty("jwt")]
        private string jwt;

        public string Jwt
        {
            get { return jwt; }
            set { jwt = value; }
        }
    }

    public class ReturnLogin
    {
        private Content content { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("success")]
        private bool isValid;

        public bool IsValid
        {
            get { return isValid; }
            set { isValid = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Este sería el servicio que estoy manejando realizando una petición POST:

```
   public async Task<MensajeError> LoginCliente(Usuario usuario) //Método (POST) para el login de usuario
    {
        try
        {
            var url = GlobalVariables.BASE_URL + GlobalVariables.AUTHENTICATION_URL + usuario.UserName + "/" + usuario.Password;

            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            response =  await client.PostAsync(url, null);
            string responseMessage = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var returnLogin = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReturnLogin> (responseMessage);


            if (returnLogin.IsValid)
            {
                mensajeError.Message = "Exitoso";
                mensajeError.HasError = true;
            }
            else
            { 
                mensajeError.Message = "Nombre de usuario o contraseña incorrecto";
                mensajeError.HasError = false;
            }
        }
        catch(HttpRequestException)
        {
            mensajeError.Message = "Error de Comunicación";
            mensajeError.HasError = false;
        }

        return mensajeError;
    }
}
```

Y este el Json que me devuelve el Web Service

```
{
    "content": {
        "jwt": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJvc3BpbWFuOThAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiUk9MRVMiOiJST0xFX0NMSUVOVCIsIlVTRVJOQU1FIjoib3NwaW1hbjk4QGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsIkNMSUVOVFRZUEUiOjEsImV4cCI6MTU4NjE0MjM1MywiaWF0IjoxNTg2MDU1OTUzLCJDTElFTlQiOjl9.CVLKhhsDAMG_Yg6tyk6c9uT0ppYilI9ZDKg9sU-XTiI0qW_i3cPBod0sW79oOD9lBjeZiCtoOcd_Hzo24FeW0Q"
    },
    "success": true
}
```

En el momento de querer sacar el jwt al modelo siempre me aparece como null, solo me logra retornar el success.

Gracias

Comment: El nombre del archivo del Modelo es ReturnLogin.cs

Answer (score 0):

Quizas con la siguiente linea funcione, lo que sucede es que la propiedad jwt esta anidada dentro de content, por eso no la encuentra.

```
[JsonProperty("content.jwt")]
```